# Site/API/Class to download real text ads for a specified keyword, like the ones that are displayed in the right side of Google

Tags: c#, html, api, text, ads

For a project (test program) I need a list of text ads based on a keyword. For example, for *"notebook"* I need one or more text ads, like

> "Cheap Notebooks Hardware for Home or Office. Deals on Cheap Notebooks! Laptop.BizRate.com" (random, taken from Yahoo when searching for *notebook*)

or

> "Notebook Computer - China Notebook Computer Supplier. High Quality, Competitive Price. Made-in-China.com/Notebook_Computer" (random, taken from Google when searching for *notebook*)

Of course, I could download a Google search page for *notebook* and extract the ads from there by parsing the HTML.

But is there an easier way? Maybe some site or api already offers this. I'm using Windows/C# but any Web/xml/etc. api would do.

I'm not interested in signing up for any account, it's not for monetization purposes. Also, I need the actual text, so I cannot just insert a Webbrowser component with an IFRAME. Of course, I don't want to build a list/database of text ads in my program, I want to download them from the Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google offers the AdWords API. You could try that one. [AdWords Homepage](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/)